# Error when adding map inside fragment tab

Tags: java, android, xml, google-maps, android-fragments

I've created an app where first of three fragment tabs contains a map. Only first tab is now implemented. You can find whole app at repository:
https://github.com/lwach87/EarthquakeApp

The app is building normally and works when I'm shifting tabs from 1 to 3. The crash appears when I'm trying back to previous tabs from tab 3. I get a runtime exception:

```
03-04 20:27:53.809 29056-29056/com.example.lwach.earthquakeapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                 Process: com.example.lwach.earthquakeapp, PID: 29056
                                                                                 android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class fragment
                                                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:770)
                                                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:483)
                                                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:415)
                                                                                     at com.example.lwach.earthquakeapp.MapFragment.onCreateView(MapFragment.java:24)
                                                                                     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2189)
                                                                                     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1299)
                                                                                     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1528)
                                                                                     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:752)
                                                                                     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2355)
                                                                                     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2146)
                                                                                     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.optimizeAndExecuteOps(FragmentManager.java:2098)
                                                                                     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execSingleAction(FragmentManager.java:1979)
                                                                                     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitNowAllowingStateLoss(BackStackRecord.java:626)
                                                                                     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:143)
                                                                                     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1268)
                                                                                     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItemInternal(ViewPager.java:668)
                                                                                     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItemInternal(ViewPager.java:630)
                                                                                     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItem(ViewPager.java:611)
                                                                                     at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout$ViewPagerOnTabSelectedListener.onTabSelected(TabLayout.java:2178)
                                                                                     at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.dispatchTabSelected(TabLayout.java:1155)
                                                                                     at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.selectTab(TabLayout.java:1148)
                                                                                     at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.selectTab(TabLayout.java:1118)
                                                                                     at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout$Tab.select(TabLayout.java:1413)
                                                                                     at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout$TabView.performClick(TabLayout.java:1523)
                                                                                     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:20926)
                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5951)
                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1388)
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1183)
                                                                                  Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Binary XML file line #1: Duplicate id 0x7f1000c0, tag null, or parent id 0x7f1000bf with another fragment for com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment
                                                                                     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:3420)
                                                                                     at android.support.v4.view.LayoutInflaterCompatHC$FactoryWrapperHC.onCreateView(LayoutInflaterCompatHC.java:47)
                                                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater$FactoryMerger.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:178)
                                                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:732)
                                                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:483) 
                                                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:415) 
                                                                                     at com.example.lwach.earthquakeapp.MapFragment.onCreateView(MapFragment.java:24) 
                                                                                     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2189) 
                                                                                     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1299) 
                                                                                     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1528) 
                                                                                     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:752) 
                                                                                     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2355) 
                                                                                     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2146) 
                                                                                     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.optimizeAndExecuteOps(FragmentManager.java:2098) 
                                                                                     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execSingleAction(FragmentManager.java:1979) 
                                                                                     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitNowAllowingStateLoss(BackStackRecord.java:626) 
                                                                                     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:143) 
                                                                                     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1268) 
                                                                                     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItemInternal(ViewPager.java:668) 
                                                                                     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItemInternal(ViewPager.java:630) 
                                                                                     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItem(ViewPager.java:611) 
                                                                                     at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout$ViewPagerOnTabSelectedListener.onTabSelected(TabLayout.java:2178) 
                                                                                     at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.dispatchTabSelected(TabLayout.java:1155) 
                                                                                     at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.selectTab(TabLayout.java:1148) 
                                                                                     at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.selectTab(TabLayout.java:1118) 
                                                                                     at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout$Tab.select(TabLayout.java:1413) 
                                                                                     at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout$TabView.performClick(TabLayout.java:1523) 
                                                                                     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:20926) 
                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5951) 
                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1388) 
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1183) 

android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class fragment com.example.lwach.earthquakeapp.MapFragment.onCreateView
```

MainActivity.java

```
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TabLayout tabLayout;
    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private Toolbar toolbar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
        viewPager.setAdapter(new PagerAdapter(this, getSupportFragmentManager()));

        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

    }
}
```

Here's the adapter for ViewPager

```
public class PagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private Context context;

    public PagerAdapter(Context context, FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return new MapFragment();
            case 1:
                return new ListFragment();
            case 2:
                return new GraphFragment();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        switch(position){
            case 0:
                return context.getString(R.string.action_map);
            case 1:
                return context.getString(R.string.action_list);
            case 2:
                return context.getString(R.string.action_graph);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

MapFragment

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MapFragment extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_map, container, false);

        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) this.getChildFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

        return view;
    }


    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show the entire stacktrace.

Comment: please copy and paste it. Not everyone views this site with a high res monitor.

Comment: Ok, I have fix that.

Comment: Thanks. Hopefully your question will be helpful to anyone else who encounters the same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is most likely due to using a SupportMapFragment nested inside a Fragment that is used in a ViewPager.

The easiest solution is to just have the Fragment that is used in the ViewPager extend SupportMapFragment directly.  This eliminates the use of nested Fragments.  Also note that inflating an xml layout is not needed with this solution.

Replace your MapFragment with this code:

```
public class MapFragment extends SupportMapFragment implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        if (mMap == null) {
            getMapAsync(this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
    }
}
```